# Serialport DataRecieved threads ending before execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, serial-port

I have noticed that when the new thread is started from serialport Data received event that if the plan of execution includes just a few methods that may change some value and send on another port then it works fine, but if the method needs to do more extensive processing like sending on another port and waiting for ACK, send again and receiving decent sized amounts of data (20KB) in 256 byte packets then the thread just stops somewhere and never completes. When the code is stepped through it seems to work fine. I have read other topics of people asking about this issue but there was no "solution" just to use another method like timers to poll the ports instead. I even made a workaround by having the main thread "poll" a variable that is changed from the event rather then having the event do the work and this seems to work, but when using a windows form I had to create a new thread which seems to be doing the same thing and either not completing the code or not executing the new thread which is just a while look that runs forever checking a variable. I can provide code if needed just wanted some insight on how to address this properly.

Comment: Your wall of text is a little confusing. Can you please state what you're trying to accomplish, a dumbed down high level example of what you're currently trying to do to accomplish it, and what the unexpected result is that you're getting?

Comment: I use C# serial ports all the time, it has some well known limitations, but mostly it's pretty straight forward, I run various protocols transferring 100Kbs of data.

Comment: I want to know what limitations are expected from data received threads and why they die while executing multiple other methods. I can give a code example but i'd need to know you like to see as the application is quite large. Basically about 4 or 5 methods are called after a certain byte array is received and goes on to do thing like send back ACK, relay byte to another port, wait for ACK, request image from camera, move image to another port and send packages of that image. It just never seems to complete yet it does when i step though it.

Answer (score -1):

Nobody here knew the answer to the questions or explained limitations, but i was able to get around the issues using timers to run while loops checking for variable changes and starting threads that did the same.